# python dictionary from config parser if value and "%(" in value: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, config, configparser

Getting this error in as random, sometimes appear, sometimes not:

```
for i in range(1,32):
    sezione = "GRP"+str(i)
    dizionarioGRP = dict(config.items(sezione))
    print int(dizionarioGRP['r'])
```

and this is the error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/pi/gigi.py", line 436, in run
    self.esegui()
  File "/home/pi/gigi.py", line 307, in esegui
    L.gruppo(idgruppo)
  File "/home/pi/gigi1.py", line 282, in gruppo
    dizionarioGRP = dict(config.items(sezione))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 655, in items
    for option in options]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 663, in _interpolate
    if value and "%(" in value:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

why it is referring as int, if I've converted it in a string?

Comment: yes, you paste the wrong lines of your code, check the line number an d paste, please.

Comment: could you paste your config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you're doing this:

```
config.set('something', 'something', 0) # or some integer
```

Or optionally you're passing in a non-string value in your `ConfigParser` constructor `dict`.

This is subtly against what the docs say:

> If the given section exists, set the given option to the specified
>   value; otherwise raise NoSectionError. While it is possible to use
>   RawConfigParser (or ConfigParser with raw parameters set to true) for
>   internal storage of non-string values, **full functionality (including
>   interpolation and output to files) can only be achieved using string
>   values.**

So whenever you call `ConfigParser.set`, make sure you wrap what you're setting in `str`.  Otherwise it throws an error when it runs through all the values in `_interpolate`.  (I consider some part of this behavior a bug, but it's probably kept as-is for backwards compatibility.  Or something.)

Another good thing to do is use [`SafeConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#safeconfigparser-objects) which will throw a `TypeError` if you try to set a non-string value, so you know this won't happen again.

Comment: It could also be in a dictionary of defaults passed in when the ConfigParser instance is made.